# Django, problems with HTMX: dependent combobox doesn't work. First combobox is populated correctly, but second is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a `country` combobox and a `trip` combobox. Both are employees. They use the same table of a database (i don't want to use two tables with foreignkey). I think i came close to the solution, but something is not working. The first combobox is populated correctly, while the second combobox is empty (as you can see in my picture).

[image]

For example, if i select `Spain` in Country, in the combobox trip I should see: `Madrid-Barcelona`, and then `Sevilla-Bilbao`, because they are in the same database table:

```
ID | COUNTRY | DEPARTURE | DESTINATION |

   | france  | paris     | lyon        | 
   | france  | marseilles| grenoble    | 
   | spain   | madrid    | barcelona   | 
   | spain   | seville   | bilbao      |
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Trip(models.Model):
  country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  departure = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  destination = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  @property
  def journey(self):
    return f"{self.departure}-{self.destination}"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.trip_selector, name="trip_selector"),
    path('', views.trips, name='trips')
]
```

**form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}

<!-- First Combobox -->
<label for="id_country">Country</label>

<select name="country" id="id_country" 
        hx-get="{% url 'trips' %}" 
        hx-target="#id_trip" 
        hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator">
  {% for country in countries %}
  <option value="{{ country }}">{{ country }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<!-- Second Combobox ??????? (non lo so)-->
<label for="id_trip">Trip</label>
{% include "trips.html" %}


{% endblock %}
```

**trips.html**

```
<!-- Second Combobox -->
<select name="trips" id="id_trip">
    {% for trip in trips %}
      <option value="{{ trip.id }}">{{ trip.departure }}-{{ trip.destination }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Trip


def trip_selector(request):
  ...
  countries = Trip.objects.values_list('country', flat=True).distinct()
  trips = []  # no trips to start with
  return render(request, 'form.html', {"countries": countries, "trips": trips})

def trips(request):
  country = request.GET.get('country')
  trips = Trip.objects.filter(country=country)
  return render(request, 'trips.html', {"trips": trips})
```

For completeness of the question, in case you want to test the code, then I also paste the code **base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>University</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    
    <!-- HTMX -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.0"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container mt-4">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone help me please. Thank you all!!!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the web console? The target could be an issue at first glance. My approcah would be to wrap the second select around div and target that div's ID from the first select (that's because htmx is targetting element using innerHTML).

Comment: @mariodev No errors from the console. Could you show me an answer on how to fix the problem? I'm new to Django and Htmx. I will gladly accept your answer in case it helps. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

When you're returning the second select box content, you need to return options list only. Currently you're including select tag, which I'm guessing is causing the issue.

Try to remove select tag from `trips.html` and move it outside of the include block like this.

```
<label for="id_trip">Trip</label>
<select name="trips" id="id_trip">
    {% include "trips.html" %}
</select>
```

Comment: It does not work. In form.html I replaced hx-target="#id_trip" with hx-target="#id_trip_div". Then I copied your code (second combobox) and replaced it in trip.html. The second combobox still remains empty. How come?

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer after taking another look into this example:
https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/

Comment: Tried. It still doesn't work :(

Comment: Do you get any response from the backend when calling ajax request? Also try to updated htmx library to the newest 1.9.3 just to make sure it's all up-to-date. Thanks.

Comment: It does not work yet. I have updated the library. What do you mean by response from backend? I'm using Visual Code and everything is ok. If you are sure that the code you wrote works correctly, can you write me the complete code of trips.html and form.html? (maybe I did something wrong and didn't apply your answer correctly). Thank you. But for now it still doesn't work

Comment: Or maybe the problem will be something else

Comment: @Horiatiki It would be easier to know if changing the first select is actually triggering the request from `trips` view. If it does - are you getting the proper html response with the list of options? You can verify it by looking at the web console -> network -> Fetch/XHR (assuming you're using chrome)

Comment: No, changing the first selection is not activating the trips request. For example, if I select Italy, then the second combobox remains empty as in the image of my question.

I checked on Chrome like you said. I had never used this tool before. When I select for example Italy, in Fetch/XHR I get: Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?country=Italy
Inquiry Method:
GET
State Code:
200 OK

Comment: And then, in addition to the comment above, I also get this: Accept:
*/*
Accept Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Connection:
keep-alive
Hosts:
127.0.0.1:8000
Hx-Current-Url:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Hx-Request:
true
Hx-Target:
id_trip
Hx-Trigger:
id_country
Hx-Trigger-Name:
country
Referrers:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?1
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Android"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty

Comment: Great, we're one step ahead, seems like the select is triggering the request after all. Now can you please click on the `?country=Italy` request from the XHR list and check preview. You should see an html content with the list of options for select box. Can you confirm?